# How to output "#" in title in mardkown file?

Tags: markdown

I want to write "`C#`"as a title. But when I input "`#C#`", it outputs as:

```
C
```

not:

```
C#
```

How to output "`#`" in title in mardkown file? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HTML entity of `#`:

```
# C&#35;
```

produces:

## C#

Answer (score 2):

Use `\#` per the Markdown [syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) page:

## C#

Comment: It works in the StackOverflow editor (but seems to require a trailing space for some reason).